# Does $XWX + WXX = 2WX$ lead do $X=I_n$?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $X,W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be square and symmetric real matrices. Does the fact that
$$
XWX + WXX = 2WX
$$
lead necessarily to $X=I_n$? Obviously $X=I_n$ satisfies the above equation, but does the converse hold true?

Comment: If $X$ is invertible, then this can be rewritten as $XW + WX = 2W$, or equivalently $(X - I)W + W(X - I) = 0$.

Comment: If $W$ is a diagonal matrix with zeroes and ones on diagonal, then you can simply put $X=W$.

Comment: mild variation: if $W=I$ then you are asing for $X^2=X$ i.e. a projection

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for your comment, I also arrived to this (by assuming that X is invertible, which I don't know in general), but what could I make of this? Does this trivially lead to $I$ being the identity matrix? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: It is just a simpler form of the equation to look at. As the other comments have stated, there are a few solutions with $X \neq I$

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!

Comment: @nullgeppetto there's a name for this equation that Ben got that I can't recall, but this is a linear equation for $W$ fixed. So if you reshape to make a matrix into vector, this should be uniquely solvable under the condition Ben gives below (hello from the future)

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)

Comment: @CalvinKhor It will be uniquely solvable for $X$ if and only if $W$ and $-W$ have no common eigenvalues, which is to say that $W$ is invertible (does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue) and has no pair of eigenvalues of the form $\pm \lambda$.

Comment: oh, thank you for the correction!

Comment: Another counterexample:
$$
X = \pmatrix{3 & 0\\0 & -1}, \quad W = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann excellent, thank you very much for bringing this up.